# Is it solvable to get line's values in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, linechart, cubic-spline

I am relatively new at data visualization. I have a line chart, however I know only few points on chart, and these points are linked with Cubic interpolation. I have built a similar chart like that: https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/interpolation-modes.html. My question is that, is it solvable to find the line's values, for example when x is 4.5? I haven't really found any information about my issue, so I thought maybe somebody dealt with similar task.

I am open for any other solutions and for any other Javascipt libraries.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I didn't really understood your question. Maybe an example of what exactly you looking for, in image format? or have some example of what you already did in a plunker or similar?

Comment: Given a line with data that has x-axis points [0,1,2,3,4,5], can we figure out what the y-value will be on the line for the x-axis point of 4.5?